# Is it unprofessional or a sign of weakness to ask for a pep talk?

Tags: morale

If you feel that morale is somewhat low on a team, is it a good idea to ask for a pep talk from a well-respected, team leaders, if you think it would increase morale?  Or would there be any negatives for asking for a pep talk, such as being viewed as "weak" or unprofessional?

Comment: Why is morale down? Why haven't the leaders noticed that it is down, and why do they need to be reminded to do something about it? What would be the goals of the pep talk?

Comment: @jmac I left out why morale is down because I didn't think it was necessary to answer the question.  Do you disagree?

Comment: It makes a big difference if the morale is down because of something temporary (last spurt of a tough project, cancelling a popular project) or if it's something bigger (layoffs, poor management, 20% of team members have quit in the past 3 weeks, etc.)

Comment: @jmac In my particular case, it's most like the last spurt of a tough deadline.  I think people are a bit worn out from the hard work.

Comment: Then my question is, why do the managers need to be reminded? If they are really the leaders, they should realize morale is down and automatically do what they think is best to fix it. Are the leaders worn down too? Because that becomes a very different issue entirely.

Comment: As an employee, I've found every single 'pep talk' given by management to have the absolute opposite effect.  If there is a morale problem, it probably isn't caused by a lack of pep talks.  I doubt anyone is going around saying, 'Gee - I sure wish I had a pep talk'.  It would probably make more sense to address the issues that are lowering moral, directly.  Imagine an employee with chronic tardiness issues...would you want him to start showing up on time or give his manager a 'pep talk' about making the time at the office count!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My thought is the difference between neediness vs. trying to be a good team representative is in how much the need for the pep talk is "for yourself" or "for others".  If you generally feel that the team, project, management and/or company are on the right track, but that the team isn't getting it, then asking management to communicate the good parts of the work should be something you can communicate the same way you might communicate a technical difficulty or a problem with a process - something the team needs to be more successful.

If you, yourself, are a primary center of low morale, this may fall into the category of taking the plank from your own eye before you remove the sawdust from your brother's.  It's hard to make a judgement call about "everyone's" morale if your own is very low.  At that point, you might want to pursue other forms of feedback yourself, or have private discussions with your management regarding the reasons for your own morale issues.

As a manager...

I've had requests from my own team leads along the lines of "the team perception is X, which leads to Y (bad morale particulars).  I see you really mean to have Z happen, which will result A (for awesomeness for everyone)... but I don't think the rest of the team sees the vision - can you help clarify for them/us?"

And I've always been happy for that - it's rare that someone on my team (even a team lead) is clued in and thoughtful enough to see this sort of gap and even rarer that they have the confidence/trust to raise it to me, so I usually take the request seriously, and at least consider it.  I may check in with others, and look for verification before pulling out my Inspirational Soapbox...

And that's where the honesty with yourself comes in - if you're the one with the worst morale on the team, and your (hopefully clueful) manager does his/her homework, then he'll figure that out, and it might be perceived as neediness.  But if you can really express this as a communication gap and a shortfall in understand the vision/strategy then you are really addressing a problem that can easily be fixed.

This is an area, though, where you want to leave the implementation up to management - be cautious in suggesting too many specifics - focus on the gap and let management figure out who/what/how the problem is addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends a lot on your relationship with this particular leader.

I've gone to my boss many times and said things along the lines of "You know boss, I think a quick pep talk from you would really give the team some much-needed energy right about now."

But I've worked with my boss for many years, I give him feedback and suggestions on his work as a boss many times, and I've never felt worried about doing so. He seems to always accept my comments in the spirit they are given.

Your mileage may vary - it depends solely on the two of you. Think about your relationship, then decide your course of action.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask people directly, they are less likely to tell you they need a pep-talk. Most people don't handle praise very well and appear uncomfortable when they get it. This causes a problem for a leader/person giving the praise because they're getting negative reinforcement.

Good leaders fight through this and give praise anyway. Deep down we all like being appreciated whether we admit it or not. Being expected to "just do your job" only goes so far. Assure people if the situation is temporary, so everyone knows there is a light at the end of the tunnel. People may need to manage family expecations through these tought times.

There is a risk of not being perceived as sincere about the situation. The boss may say these are tough times and expectations are too high, but you'll lose people if you overly punish them for failure or hold them responsible for things they cannot control.

Answer (score 0):

My caution here is how you frame it.  If you make it sound like the team is doing poor work and requires some face time with management to get up to doing acceptable work, then yes there would be negatives from almost all sides in making this kind of request as it expresses negative opinions of both sides of things here.

On the other hand, if you frame it as a, "Our team would be even greater if you came in to say a few words in the morning to build the relationships even stronger than they are already," then it may seem like it is a win/win situation that would be more desirable.  The manager gets to have a closer relationship with that team and the team gets the encouragement to help do an even better job.  The key here is that there isn't that negative opinion expressed but rather going towards something better that may be attractive to people here.

Course I would note that this presumes the issue is primarily within motivation rather than the team having low energy as they recharge after doing a long hard project that they want some down time.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: asking honest questions is NEVER unprofessional.  Or sign of weakness.

Certainly you must ask proper questions, do your work to discover even that part, and make sure to learn from answers, or seek further.